# If the area of square A and rectangle B are equal what will be relation between their perimeters?

Tags: geometry

I found by actual calculation that the perimeter of Square A will be less than the perimeter of Rectangle B, but how to formalize it mathematically?

Comment: Hint:  if the side of the square is $s$ then the rectangle with the same perimeter has sides $(s+x,s-x)$ for some $x$.

Comment: Sorry i hit return button for next line.                                                         
It will be give $$s^2 > (s^2) - (x^2)$$ which is formalization for same perimeter and different area, but i can not formalize such for same area.

Comment: Do you want just a statement like "among all rectangles with given area, the square has smallest perimeter" or a proof of this sort of statement?

Comment: I am trying to write a formal proof.

Comment: you have the wrong approach. If you show that the square will have the biggest are of all rectangles with the same perimeter, then rectangle with the same area as a square will always have bigger perimeter.

Comment: If $4s$ is the perimeter of the rectangle then the area is $s^2-x^2$ for some $x$.  if $4S$ is the perimeter of the unique square with the same area then we have $S^2=s^2-x^2\implies s=\sqrt  {S^2+x^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M^2$ be the area of the square, with $M>0$. Then, the side length of the square is $M.$ Moreover, The rectangle has sides $M+s$ and $\frac{M^2}{M+s}$, where we can assume $s\ge0$. In fact:

$$Area(A) = M^2 = (M+s)\frac{M^2}{M+s} = Area(B).$$

Now, the perimetere of $A$ and $B$ are, respectively
$$p(A) = 4M \qquad\text{and}\qquad p(B)=2\left(M+s+\frac{M^2}{M+s}\right).$$

So now you need to prove that
$$4M \le 2\left(M+s+\frac{M^2}{M+s}\right),\quad\text{when }s\ge0.$$

Comment: Thank you for this neat explanation, i managed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Given any rectangle with area $A$. Let $a, b$ be its sides and $p$ is its perimeter.

We have $p = 2(a+b)$ and $A = ab$. By AM $\ge$ GM, we have

$$p = 2(a+b) = 4\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \ge 4\sqrt{ab} = 4\sqrt{A}$$

This means the perimeter for any rectangle with area $A$ is bounded from below by $4\sqrt{A}$.

Since a square with side $\sqrt{A}$ has area $A$ and perimeter $4\sqrt{A}$,
above lower bound is achieved by a square. From this, we can conclude

> Among all rectangle with a given area $A$, the square has the smallest perimeter $4\sqrt{A}$.

Comment: Thank you for adding a new dimension to answer given by AugSB, it added a new and excellent dimension.